# Помогите понять как работает множественное наследование в моем коде

Tags: c++, алгоритм, наследование, множественное-наследование

Вопрос звучит таким образом:  При создании объекта типа С в конструктор класса А передавать разные значения через конструкторы В. Что останется в поле класса А?

````
using namespace std;

class A1 {
protected:
    int a1;
public:
    A1(int input = 0) : a1(input) {
        cout << "A1 constructor" << endl;
    }
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "variable of A1 class" << endl;
    }
    virtual void show() {
        cout << "a1=" << a1 << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class B1 : virtual public A1 {
protected:
    int b1;
public:
    B1(int input1, int input2) : A1(input1), b1(input2) {
        cout << "B1 constructor" << endl;
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "variable of B1 class" << endl;
    }
    void show() override {
        cout << "a1=" << a1 << ", b1=" << b1 << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class B2 : virtual public A1 {
protected:
    int b2;
public:
    B2(int input1, int input2) : A1(input1), b2(input2) {
        cout << "B2 constructor" << endl;
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "variable of B2 class" << endl;
    }
    void show() override {
        cout << "a1=" << a1 << ", b2=" << b2 << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class B3 : virtual public A1 {
protected:
    int b3;
public:
    B3(int input1, int input2) : A1(input1), b3(input2) {
        cout << "B3 constructor" << endl;
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "variable of B3 class" << endl;
    }
    void show() override {
        cout << "a1=" << a1 << ", b3=" << b3 << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class B4 : virtual public A1 {
protected:
    int b4;
public:
    B4(int input1, int input2) : A1(input1), b4(input2) {
        cout << "B4 constructor" << endl;
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "variable of B4 class" << endl;
    }
    void show() override {
        cout << "a1=" << a1 << ", b4=" << b4 << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class C1 : virtual public B1, virtual public B2, virtual public B3, virtual public B4 {
protected:
    int c1;
public:
    C1(int input1, int input2, int input3, int input4, int input5, int input6) : B1(input1, input2), B2(input1, input3), B3(input1, input4), B4(input1, input5), c1(input6) {
        cout << "C1 constructor" << endl;
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "variable of C1 class" << endl;
    }
    void show() override {
        cout << "b1= " << b1 << ", b2= " << b2 << ", b3= " << b3 << ", b4= " << b4 << ", c1= " << c1 << "\n" << endl;
    }
};


class C2 : virtual public B1, virtual public B2, virtual public B3, virtual public B4 {
protected:
    int c2;
public:
    C2(int input1, int input2, int input3, int input4, int input5, int input6) : B1(input1, input2), B2(input1, input3), B3(input1, input4), B4(input1, input5), c2(input6) {
        cout << "C2 constructor" << endl;
    }
    void print() override {
        cout << "variable of C2 class" << endl;
    }
    void show() override {
        cout << "b1= " << b1 << ", b2= " << b2 << ", b3= " << b3 << ", b4= " << b4 << ", c2= " << c2 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    if (true) {
        A1 ex1(1);
        ex1.print();
        ex1.show();

        B1 ex2(22, 33);
        ex2.print();
        ex2.show();

        B2 ex3(444, 555);
        ex3.print();
        ex3.show();

        C1 ex4(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6);
        ex4.print();
        ex4.show();

        C2 ex5(11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66);
        ex5.print();
        ex5.show();
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виртуальной базовый класс должен инициализировать только тот объект, который создаётся. В `C1 ext4` , `C2 ex5` класс `A1` будет инициализирован конструктором по-умолчанию **один** раз `A1()`. То-есть нулём.
А если добавите инициализацию `C2(..):A(x),..` , то будет **один** раз с аргументом `x`.
*Конструкторы в **B** классах не будут участвовать в инициализации **A** класса.*